# Why is my evalPostfix method not working?

Tags: java, eval, infix-notation

In my Java program file, I am trying to write a method that will evaluate a postfix expression.

I am also trying to write an eval() method for my Expression class that evaluates an infix expression by first converting it to postfix and then evaluating the postfix.

For example, in main, if I write: eval("1 + 2 * 3") I should get 7.

However, in my program, when I write this, all it returns is -1.

Can anyone help me pinpoint the error in my code, either in the evalPostfix() or eval() methods?

```
public class Expression {
   private static final String SPACE = " ";
   private static final String PLUS = "+";
   private static final String MINUS = "-";


   public static int rank(String operator) {
      switch (operator) {
         case "^":       //5
            return 3;
         case "*":
         case "/":
            return 2;
         case PLUS:
         case MINUS:     //2
            return 1;
         case "()":      //6
            return 0;
         default:
            return -1;
      }
   }

   public static boolean isOperator(String token) {     //4
      if (rank(token) > 0){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static int applyOperator(String operator,int op1,int op2){     //7
      switch (operator) {
         case PLUS:
            return op1+op2;
         case MINUS:
            return op1-op2;
         case "*":
            return op1*op2;
         case "/":
            return op1/op2;
         case "^":
            return (int) Math.pow( (double) op1, (double) op2);    //9
         default:
            return -1;
      }
   }

   public static String toPostfix(String infixExpr) {
      StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
      Stack<String> operators = new ArrayStack<>();
      Stack<Character> s = new ArrayStack<Character>();    //6
      for (int i = 0; i < infixExpr.length(); i++){
         if(infixExpr.charAt(i) == '(');
            s.push('(');
         if(infixExpr.charAt(i) == ')' && !operators.isEmpty()){
            s.pop();
            if(s.isEmpty()) 
               output.append(s.pop());
            if(s.pop() != '(') 
               operators.pop();
            }
         }

      for (String token: infixExpr.split("\\s+")) {
         if (isOperator(token)) { // operator //4
            // pop equal or higher precedence
            while (!operators.isEmpty() &&
                  rank(operators.peek()) >= rank(token)) {
               output.append(operators.pop() + SPACE);
            }
            operators.push(token);
         } else {               // operand
            output.append(token + SPACE);
         }
      }
      while (!operators.isEmpty()) {
         output.append(operators.pop() + SPACE);
      }
      return output.toString();
   }

    public static int evalPostfix(String infixExpr) {     //8
      Stack <String> s = new ArrayStack<String>();
      String operand = null;
      for(int i = 0; i < infixExpr.length(); i++) {
         if (Character.isDigit(infixExpr.charAt(i)))
             s.push(infixExpr.charAt(i) + "");
         else {
             if (s.size() > 1) {
                int value1 = Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
                int value2 = Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
                s.push(applyOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i) + "", value1, value2) + "");
             }
         }
      }
      return Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
      }

   public static int eval(String infix){
      return evalPostfix(toPostfix(infix));
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(rank("/"));
      String infix = "(a * b) * c + d ^ e / f";
      String stat = "5 * 3";
      System.out.println(toPostfix(infix));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 7 * 3 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("*", 3, 7));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 50 + 12 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("+", 50, 12));
      System.out.print("Using Math.pow to perform exponentiation, 6 to the 2nd power is: ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("^", 6,2));
      System.out.println(eval(stat));
      }
   }
```

Comment: In my program, I use String stat = "5 * 3" which should return 15, but it returns -1

Comment: Perhaps today is a good day to learn about the debugger. Step through the code, and you should be able to find your bug(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hmmm, its been 30 minutes and I am still unsure on what to do. Are there any other tips that would help me?